# Edit button + populate field with redux / react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux

I need send the data line from DataTable to another page and populate the fields with React or Redux... how can i do that?

[image]

```
class Dtable extends Component {

    componentWillMount() {
        this.props.getList();
    }

    actionTemplate(rowData, column) {
        return <div>
            <Button type="button" icon="fa-search" className="ui-button-success"></Button>
            <Button type="submit" icon="fa-edit"  onClick={console.log(column)} className="ui-button-warning" ></Button>
        </div>
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Form onSubmit={this.props.create} />
                <div className="content-section implementation" style={{ paddingTop: 1 + '%' }}>
                    <DataTable key="idPessoa" value={this.props.list} paginator={true} paginator={true} rows={10} rowsPerPageOptions={[5, 10, 20]} >
                        <Column field="idPessoa" header="Propriedade" style={{ width: 5 + '%' }} />
                        <Column field="nome" header="Propriedade" />
                        <Column field="email" header="Propriedade" />
                        <Column field="latitude" header="Relatório" style={{ width: 15 + '%' }} />
                        <Column field="longitude" header="Ativo" style={{ width: 5 + '%' }} />
                        <Column header="Opções" body={this.actionTemplate} style={{ textAlign: 'center', width: '100px' }} />
                    </DataTable>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }

}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({ list: state.upload.list })
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => bindActionCreators({ getList, create, showUpdate }, dispatch)
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Dtable)
```

Comment: Can you post your components so that we can help something here? One thing that you can do is, when you click on edit, pass the selected row data from your table component as props to the component in which your text box lies

Comment: can you give an exampe that how can i do that?

Comment: What is the component that you are using? react-datatable?

Comment: DataTable - Templating from Prime React.

Comment: Would it be possible to create a code snippet for us to check the issue?

Comment: G_S I have two fields and when a click on button edit i want that fields receives the values..

Comment: To be honesty I need edit a register line..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just add the arrow function on my event ..this solve my problem..thanks guys.

```
 actionTemplate = (rowData, column) => {
    return <div>
        <Button type="button" icon="fa-search" imediate='true' onClick={() => this.teste(rowData.nome,rowData.email)} className="ui-button-success"></Button>
        <Button type="button" icon="fa-edit" imediate='true'
         onClick={() => console.log(rowData)} className="ui-button-warning" ></Button>
    </div>
}


teste = (nome,mail) => {

    console.log(nome)
    this.setState({name:nome,email:mail})

}
```